# Where is the return value of a function stored?

Tags: function, language-agnostic

I assume this question is language agnostic, and apologies if it's quite rudimentary, but say we have (PHP in this example)

`function myFunc() {
    return 4;
}`

Now when this function is called, usually the result will be used in an expression or be assigned to a variable. But if it's not assigned to a variable, where does the return value "live" when it's been called? Is there an internal structure that keeps it in memory for the purpose of the current statement, and when that statement is executed, it removes it again?

Comment: It's not really language agnostic, because it depends a lot on the specific language (and may even vary between different implementations of the same language).

Comment: Often the return value is passed down the call stack. But this is in no way language (implementation, really) -agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Note: C++ specific*) In most cases compiler will user **[Return Value Optimisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)** and store value in the variable that gets the result of the function assigned to.

For example:

```
int myInt = myFunc();
```

will cause the pointer to `myInt` varaible to by passed to `myFunc` on the stack so `myFunc` will work directly with `myInt` without creating a new variable.

Otherwise the function returns by placing the return value on the stack.

I think in .NET it's called [**Name Return Value Optimization**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slippman/archive/2004/02/03/66739.aspx).

Other compilers probably have similar features in place.

Answer (score 2):

If you just do something like:

```
var foo = bar();
myFunc();
var wibble = baz();
```

Then a Number `4` will be created for the return statement, then immediately will be discarded as there aren't any references to it.

Comment: Righto, so say we had a more complex statement like myFunc() + ComplexFunction(); - and we say that ComplexFunction() takes a long time to evaluate, is then the return value of myFunc() kept somewhere in memory until the whole statement has been evaluated, and if so, is there a name for this?

Answer (score 0):

> so say we had a more complex statement like myFunc() + ComplexFunction()

I think this one depends on the compiler and it's [register allocation scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation).

The compiler could store the result for `myFunc()` in a register, then jump to execute `ComplexFunction()`. On entering `ComplexFunction()`, the registers would be saved on the stack and the restored when returning.